# My templates don't extend properly to 'base.html'

Tags: python, django, templates, inheritance

I'm using the template system to develop the different pages of my site. I have a 'base.html' which is the base template, where there are static (with no {%blocks%}) the common features in all my site's pages, as the header and the nav menu.

I'm making some changes on it, like introducing the text on the header to the 'login' and 'logout', also creating the links on the menu elements.

When I go to other template (which extends 'base.html'), it loads it all good, but for example those 'login' new features on top div and also the links on the menu aren't shown. Aren't they common if the template extends to 'base.html'? I'll show you pieces of code:

'base.html' has this code:

```
<body>

<header>
<div class="topbox">
    <!-- <img src="static/mysite/g5794.png" alt="Logo" height="180" width="1400"> -->
</div>
<div id="auth">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Bienvenido, <b>{{ user.username }}  |  <a href=" {% url "logout" %}">Logout</a></b></p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Bienvenido, por favor <a href="{% url "login" %}">loguéate</a></p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
<p>MAIN PAGE MAIN TOP PAGE</p>
</header>

<nav>
    <div class="menu">
        <p><a href="{% url "index_view" %}">HOME</a> | <a href="{% url "list_index" %}">LIST</a> | <a href="">ELSE</a> | <a href="">BLOG</a></p>
    </div>
</nav>

{% block content1 %}
```

The features I mentioned don't work in any other template that extends 'base.html'. For example, the 'login.html' template, for the moment, looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}{% trans "LOGIN" %}{% endblock %}
{% include "base.html" %}

{% block content1 %}
{% block style_base %}
<link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}
    <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>login</h1>
    {% if message %}
    <b>{{message}}</b>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

All those template tags in top of the page are slightly required to inherit the styles from 'base.html' (can't find a way to extend to those styles without that much code). It loads properly the divs of the top, but it doesn't show what I mentioned (the new login/logout lines in header and the links in the nav menu). This happens the same also with 'list_index' template.

I don't know what could happen here. Is really posible that only extends to some pieces of code or can't extend to the newest? My settings.py template section looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Also tried with the 'DIRS': []. The only page where it shows all okay is in the index page (the base.html page). What happens in the other templates? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two base.html files in different places?

Comment: You should show the view that is rendering login.html.

Comment: Yes, and thank you, I had two different base.html files with those slightly differences. Now the problem is that, once changed, the page of 'list_index' doesn't get the styles from base.html (as it did before). Edited with code update.

Comment: Please share your solution by posting your own answer, not by editing your question

Comment: I just had two base.html files and that was what made the error while returning new edits.

Answer (score 0):

in base.html
I only see {% block content1 %}, do not see {% endblock content1 %}}.

Comment: Well that's because I didn't copy the whole code. This problem is now solved, but that made the styles not extend properly. The first post is edited, thank you for the answer.